# Combine referenceBlocks from 2 custom module into 3rd layout xml...Possible?

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

How to use two  from 2 different modules and call them in the 3rd layout?

say for eg:

From **CatalogSearch** module, **catalogsearch_result_index.xml** has

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="search.result">
      <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module1::result.phtml</argument>
      </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

From **CatalogLayeredNavigation** module, same xml **catalogsearch_result_index.xml** has

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock before="-" name="catalogsearch.leftnav">
      <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module2::layer/view.phtml</argument>
      </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Can i combine the referenceBlocks in **Module3** as :

```
 <body>
    <referenceBlock name="search.result">
      <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module1::result.phtml</argument>
      </action>
    </referenceBlock>

    <referenceBlock before="-" name="catalogsearch.leftnav">
      <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module2::layer/view.phtml</argument>
      </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes totally you can use as many `<referenceBlock>` / `<referenceContainer>` tag in your layout files as you want.

Comment: ok...@Raphael...I have to use similar class in Controller and Block(Result.php and Index.php respectively) in 3rd module from 1st and 2nd module's Controller and Block..Do i need to keep those classes in 3rd module.? or do i just need to override the xml layout file

Comment: By 3rd modules layout file as used above doesnt seem to be called at all...

Comment: Any suggestions on this @Raphael?

Comment: @SachinS Try disabling the modules one by one to investigate the issue