# Multiple referenceBlocks in default.xml - but only the last one applies

Tags: template, magento-2.1, xml

I have added multiple referenceBlocks in the default.xml file for the Magento theme. [Which I thought would work](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131601/combine-referenceblocks-from-2-custom-module-into-3rd-layout-xml-possible) but it appears it will only ever show which ever is last in the XML file. (i.e. if I swap custom.home to be before customer.header then the *header* element would show, and vise versa).

Note the order only makes a difference in default.xml not home.xml (the layout file). Can I have multiple reference blocks or am I missing something?

**default.xml**

```
    <!-- Removed blocks -->
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="top.links" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="header.container" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="footer" remove="true" />

    <!-- Add custom blocks -->
    <referenceBlock name="custom.header">
        <container name="globalheader" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="globalheader">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="row" template="Magento_Theme::html/globalheader.phtml">
                </block>
        </container>
    </referenceBlock>

    <referenceBlock name="custom.home">
        <container name="homehtml" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="htmlHome">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="row" template="Magento_Theme::html/home.phtml">
            </block>
        </container>
    </referenceBlock>
```

**Home.xml**

```
    <referenceContainer name="main.content" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="content" remove="true" />

    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="custom.header" as="custom_header_container" label="Page Header Container" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="custom.home" as="custom_home_container" label="Route for Static HTML Page"  />
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

Comment: Have you applied below solution ?

Comment: @SHPatel It was at the end of the day so have only just done it, it worked so thanks. Stupid error though, guess I was tired!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used same block reference name as `name="row"`

change block name like `name="row"` and `name="rowtest"` something like this.

Let me know if not working this solution.